# JavaScript AJAX Request Successful, But Returns Nothing

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, request

I've been following along a tutorial, but I just can't make it to work. One hour of trying to figure it out, but nothing. This AJAX request returns nothing. I'm a beginner. Help is appreciated.

```
      <form id="postForm">
       <input type="text" name="name" id="name1">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    document.querySelector('#postForm').addEventListener('submit', loadText5)

        function loadText5(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            let name = document.getElementById('name1').value;
            let params = "name"+name;
            let response = new XMLHttpRequest();
            response.open('POST', 'process.php', true);
           response.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

                response.onload = function() {
                console.log(this.responseText);
              }
            response.send(params);
         }
     </script>
```

Process.php

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
return 'POST: Your name is ' . $_POST['name'];
}
```

Comment: Instead of `return 'POST...` try `echo 'POST...`

Comment: Huh, thank you so much!